# VB.NET Allow user to choose directory to save multiple files to

Tags: vb.net, io, vb.net-2010, .net

I know how to open/save files, ect and do fairly well with programming. I am not a pro, but I get the job done. I know quite a bit, and am good with using Google to find my answers.

Maybe it is because I am pretty tired right now, or I am not sure what exactly I am looking for to put into Google correctly...

I am needing to allow the user to choose a directory to save in. They can create a new directory if they want/need, and once they choose the directory, my program will save a few pre-coded files into that directory.

I don't think this would use the OpenFileDialog. Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a folder select dialog, as well.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I could have found it, just didnt know "what" I was looking for.. Got it ;)

Comment: If you come back, and repost your answer in the "answer" box, I will mark it as the answer. You can't mark comments as answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seek is the folder select dialog. It lets the user do all the stuff you are loking for.